# Array insertion JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a use case as follows

```
var myObject1 = new myObject();
```

and myObject should have an array which will store all the objects created of this myObject

Example:-

if create an object such as

```
var xyz = new myObject();
myObject.all[0] == xyz
```

is there any way where - when I create an object & I can push it into an array which is in the definition of same object.

Comment: is there is any reason why the array must belong to myObject()? can't you just make a normal array and store the created objects there?

Comment: Make a singleton object that keeps track

Answer (score 4):

You can create a property directly on the constructor function, to get the `myObject.all[0] == xyz` behaviour mentioned in the question. Add each object to the array from within the constructor:

```js
function MyObject() {
  MyObject.all.push(this);
  // any other initialisation tasks here
}
MyObject.all = [];
    
var obj1 = new MyObject();
var obj2 = new MyObject();
    
// to access the array use MyObject.all:
console.log(MyObject.all[1] === obj2);  // true
```

Alternatively, you can add an array to the object prototype, but still add new objects to that array from within the constructor:

```
function MyObject() {
  this.all.push(this);
  // any other initialisation tasks here
}
MyObject.prototype.all = [];

var obj1 = new MyObject();
var obj2 = new MyObject();

// to access the array:
console.log(obj1.all);
// or
console.log(MyObject.prototype.all);

console.log(obj1.all[1] === obj2); // true
```

(Note: in both examples, I've spelled `MyObject` with a capital "M", because it is a JS convention for functions intended as constructors to be capitalised. This isn't mandatory.)

Comment: Just beat me to it :) This is a case where prototypical inheritance really shines. You'd have to use a static property or outside singleton/global in traditional OOP

Comment: @CharlieMartin - Well JS does allow `MyObject.all` and that would work fine too. I've added it to my answer, because it seems to be more what the OP wanted.

Comment: Yeah I thought the prototype was a clever way to get the full list in each instance. Looking at the code, the static property is actually a little nicer. Should have known. Clever is rarely a good thing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
function MyObject(name){
   if (!O.prototype.instances) O.prototype.instances = [];
   O.prototype.instances.push(name);
}


var a = MyObject('a');
var b = MyObject('b');

console.log(MyObject.prototype.instances)
```